# How to make certain training samples more important in keras tenserflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have data that contains a boolean feature (X),
Is there is any way to make the samples that contain x=1 more important than other samples?

NB1: By **make certain training samples more important** I mean these samples can affect the model more than other samples. I've already read something similar on this, but I haven't been able to get it right. Here is what I read:

**In TensorFlow Keras it is easy to make certain training samples more important. The normal output from class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence) is (X,y). Instead output (X,y,w) where weight is the same shape as y. Then make w=2 for all the positive targets and w=1 for all the negative targets. Then train with the usual TensorFlow Keras calls `t_gen = DataGenerator() model.fit(t_gen)`**

NB2: I am working with LSTM

Comment: Your question is not clear to me, what do you mean by "making more important" ? What kind of network are you working with ?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "more important"?

Comment: I am sorry because the question was not clear at the beginning. And I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "more important" you mean samples with x=1 will have a larger impact to the cost function than samples where x is not =1. There are two parameters in model.fit that may enable you to do this, class_weight or sample_weight. From the documentation located [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) these are described below:

```
class_weight: Optional dictionary mapping class indices (integers) to a weight
 (float) value, used for weighting the loss function (during training only). This
 can be useful to tell the model to "pay more attention" to samples from an under-represented class.

sample_weight: Optional Numpy array of weights for the training samples, used for
 weighting the loss function (during training only). You can either pass a flat (1D)
 Numpy array with the same length as the input samples (1:1 mapping between weights and samples), or in the case of temporal data, you can pass a 2D array with shape
 (samples, sequence_length), to apply a different weight to every timestep of every
 sample. This argument is not supported when x is a dataset, generator, or 
keras.utils.Sequence instance, instead provide the sample_weights as the third 
element of x.
```

In order to get the result you wish using sample_weight you will have to create a generator that produces batches of data that returns 3 values, x, y, w, where x is the sample array, y is the label array and w is the sample weight array. In your case you might want the value of w =1 for all samples where your x value is not 1 and w=2 for all samples where your x value=1. That would make samples with x=1 have twice the impact of the cost function. Information on how to build a custom generator is located [here.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Sequence) In the code you would need to determine the value of w for each sample and return a w array  along with x and y.
An easier alternative might be to use class_weight if x is a class in your data. For example assume you have a data set of the form:

```
No of Samples    Class  Class Index
   100            A        0
   200            B        1
   1700           C        2
```

Here your data set is NOT balanced and your model will tend to predict class C since if it always predicts class C it will be right 85% of the time. To deal with this we would like classes A and B to have an increased impact on the cost function. Using the class_weight parameter affords this capability. We would like class A to have
1700/100=17 times more impact on the cost function than class C, and class B to have
1700/200=8.5 times the impact on the cost function than class C so our class_weight dictionary would appear as

```
class_weight={0:17, 1:8.5, 2:1}
```